# Why is my search functionality not working with the SpaceX api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to search the names of past SpaceX launches and it's not working. I'm sourcing from the SpaceX launches API using **Axios**: https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches/past

When I try to search all that happens is that the api request is refreshed but with the same initial results, not with that is typed in the text input.

**App.js:**

```
function App() {
  const [params, setParams] = useState({});
  const {launches, loading, error} = FetchLaunches(params);

  const handleParamChange = (e) => {
    const param = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setParams(prevParams => {
      return { ...prevParams, [param]: value }
    });
  }

  return (
    <main className='app'>
      <SearchForm params={params} onParamChange={handleParamChange}/>
      <div className="launch-list">
      {loading && <h2>Loading...</h2>}
      {error && <h2>An error occured</h2>}
      {launches.map(launch => {
        return <LaunchItem
        launch={launch}
        key={launch.flight_number}
      />
      })}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

**fetch-launches.js:** gets data using the axios library:

```
const ACTIONS = {
  MAKE_REQUEST: 'make-request',
  GET_DATA: 'get-data',
  ERROR: 'error',
};

const SPACEX_URL = 'https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches/past';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.MAKE_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, launches: [] };
    case ACTIONS.GET_DATA:
      return { ...state, loading: false, launches: action.payload.launches };
    case ACTIONS.ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload.error,
        launches: [],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const FetchLaunches = (params) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    launches: [],
    loading: true,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const cancelToken1 = axios.CancelToken.source();
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.MAKE_REQUEST });
    axios
      .get(SPACEX_URL, {
        cancelToken: cancelToken1.token,
        params: { ...params },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.GET_DATA, payload: { launches: res.data } });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        if (axios.isCancel(e)) return;
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.ERROR, payload: { error: e } });
      });

    return () => cancelToken1.cancel();
  }, [params]);

  return state;
};
```

**search-form.js**:

```
const SearchForm = ({params, onParamChange}) => {
  return (
      <form className='search-form'>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='search for a launch'
          className='search-form__field'
          onChange={onParamChange}
          name='name'
          value={params.name || ''}
        />
      </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: is there any special reason to use this

setParams(prevParams => {
      return { ...prevParams, [param]: value }
    });

instead of just this setParams({...params, [param]: value })

Comment: @shashisrinath it's good practice to use the updater function `state => ({ ...state, /*etc*/ })` when the previous state is used.

Comment: I think you should be using `/launches/query` if you want to customize the response instead of getting all past launces

Comment: @AjeetShah it's returning full results every time

Comment: @EmileBergeron not really, I've seen that.

Comment: @AjeetShah using params, sorry I incorrectly added the wrong code. I was just testing with "options"